# Could not open index.scala.html in Eclipse Scala IDE

Tags: html, scala, playframework

When I try to open any scala.html file in Eclipse  I am getting this exception.
so I could not edit file. Any help will be highly appreciated.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.tools.eclipse.lexical.ScalaCodeScanner.<init>(Lorg/eclipse/jface/preference/IPreferenceStore;Lscalariform/ScalaVersion;)V
    at org.scalaide.play2.templateeditor.sse.lexical.TemplateRegionParser$$anonfun$computeRegions$1$$anonfun$2.apply(TemplateRegionParser.scala:176)
    at org.scalaide.play2.templateeditor.sse.lexical.TemplateRegionParser$$anonfun$computeRegions$1$$anonfun$2.apply(TemplateRegionParser.scala:168)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:251)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:251)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:251)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.flatMap(Traversable.scala:105)
    at org.scalaide.play2.templateeditor.sse.lexical.TemplateRegionParser$$anonfun$computeRegions$1.apply(TemplateRegionParser.scala:168)
    at org.scalaide.play2.templateeditor.sse.lexical.TemplateRegionParser$$anonfun$computeRegions$1.apply(TemplateRegionParser.scala:155)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:105)
    at org.scalaide.play2.templateeditor.sse.lexical.TemplateRegionParser.computeRegions(TemplateRegionParser.scala:155)
    at org.scalaide.play2.templateeditor.sse.lexical.TemplateRegionParser$$anonfun$1.apply(TemplateRegionParser.scala:59)
    at org.scalaide.play2.templateeditor.sse.lexical.TemplateRegionParser$$anonfun$1.apply(TemplateRegionParser.scala:59)
    at org.scalaide.play2.templateeditor.sse.lexical.TemplateRegionParser$LazyCache$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(TemplateRegionParser.scala:51)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.scalaide.play2.templateeditor.sse.lexical.TemplateRegionParser$LazyCache.apply(TemplateRegionParser.scala:50)
```

Comment: I think you'd be better off submitting a bug report to Scala IDE: https://scala-ide-portfolio.assembla.com/spaces/scala-ide/support/tickets

Comment: A new  ticket has been raised.

Comment: Aside: May I suggest you try IntelliJ? :)

Comment: I reinstalled Eclipse Juno and installed Scala IDE plugin and Play Plugin. it looks like the problem reported here is not happening any more. I tried toupdate the ticket raised in Assembla[Scala-ide] the Captcha doesnot allow me to post. I tried ten Captcha.